# Low speed of mysql connecting

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli, database-connection

I am working on mysql and php on my laptop(windows) with XAMMP .

everything is good , but as I need to communicate with mysql , I need to connect to db for first time  I create a page :

```
$mysqliu = new mysqli($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass, $db_name);
```

that takes around 1.2 second to load , but my whole page creating is about 1.23 and that mean my PHP page takes only .03 sec to load , and huge time just for connecting ?

How can I decrease this speed ?

Is in real server the same ?

Comment: This looks more like a Server Fault question than a Stack Overflow one. Regardless, needs more information. Are you referring to your host using a DNS name? How did you configure your MySQL? What version of MySQL/PHP?

Answer (score 0):

I don't use mysqli but the standard approach that I would take in this scenario is to try persistent connections. A quick look at the PHP docs indicates that mysqli supports them. You don't need to change your usage, you just need to indicate that your connection should be persistent and then work as usual. The link below describes the usage:

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.persistconns.php

Answer (score 0):

This can be due to two different problems. One is maybe your firewall's security level is too high and trying to detect your connection. Another thing is maybe hard disk is slow, fragmented too much.